# Add printer from different subnet

Tags: networking, printer, subnet

i.e

My pc ip is 11.19.20.3 with gateway 11.19.20.1

I have a printer with ip 11.19.22.25  with gateway 11.19.22.1

How can I add this printer to my pc?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you're using some version of Windows.

First make sure you can see the printer on the network. Type "ping 11.19.22.25" into a command prompt. If you get replies the printer is accessible. If ping times out, you'll need to check the settings on the router(s) to give you access to the printer.

Now go to the Add Printer wizard and add a new **local** printer (not a network printer). When asked for the port, create a new Standard TCP/IP port with the IP address of the printer. When asked for the printer model, point it to the location of the driver files.

If you're not running Windows, please tell us which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is type the IP into a web browser and see if the admin page for the printer comes up.  If that works, then you should be able to add the printer using whatever OS you are using entering the IP instead of a name for the address of the printer.

Comment: If this does not work, there's no easy way to do this reliably without configuring the routers involved, somehow getting a network interface to appear on 11.19.22.X.  If the printer has a "print from email" feature you can try enabling that as quick solution.